# Google Maps and Richfaces 3.3.3 (prototype.js 1.6.0.3) possible incompatibility

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, richfaces, prototypejs

I have a web application based on RichFaces 3.3.3 that uses Google Maps (maps-api v3), that was working fine until recently.

Lately is failing to draw the map's user controls. Map is drawn fine but the controls don't appear, map type or zoom control, for example.

Investigating a little, it seems a compatibility problem with prototype.js.

If you simply add this line to the example in [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple):

```
<script src="http://prototypejs.org/assets/2008/9/29/prototype-1.6.0.3.js"></script>
```

js console in chrome browser logs this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function       prototype-1.6.0.3.js:641
```

And the user controls dissapear...

Somebody knows how to solve this problem??

Now I'm going to try to change prototype.js in richfaces for a more modern version... I'll update when I know more.

Thanks in advance!

--- UPDATE ---

- Using production version of Google Maps solves the problem. Now is necessary explicitly put v=3 in src in script tag. Thanks Dr.Molle.
- Updating prototypejs to (1.7.2). Works fine with experimental too. Thanks @eepete.

--- UPDATE 2 ---

- Using v=3 isn't working anymore with richfaces 3.3.3 (prototype-1.6.0.3.js) if you need to use this old version of prototype, now you need to explicitly use v=3.17 in google maps.

In other words, use this in your page for backguards compatibility with prototype-1.6.0.3.js:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17"></script>
```

Comment: Try to use the release-version of the Maps-API(the demo uses the experimental version), I don't receive the error with the release-version.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning.  Got the same error, controls like the zoom control would not render.  I upgraded my prototype.js to the latest version (1.7.2) from version (1.7) and things worked again.  Am using google maps api V3, the production version.  Don't know if it was the newer version prototype.js or if Google changed something and then fixed something, but it's happy now.

Comment: I think google changed something recently in the experimental version. You can recheck that you are really using release version of maps, I was using experimental without being aware. Maybe you need to add `v=3` explicitly to your `script` tag , or maybe you have `v=3.exp` in the src and you have to remove the `.exp` part.

Comment: Anyway if you can update 'prototype.js', it seems the best solution.

Comment: The script tag I'm using is:  'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' so I'm _guessing_ that should be the production version?  If it was '..../js?v=3.exp?sensor=false' that would use the experimental.  If I understand you correctly, it would be advisable to explicitly get the production version by using the tag '..../js?v=3?sensor=false'.  I'll give that a try and thank you for your reply.

Comment: Exactly! if you put 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' in a browser you'll see at the end of the response (a js file) the line: 'getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/0/main.js");' if you put 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3' you'll see getScript("http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/17/15/main.js");. I think that 18/0 corresponds to experimental and 17/15 to production... I don't know why Google is now sending 18 by default... Anyway the problem is solved, I think I'm going to update the post and marking your answer as solution.

Comment: Just today an app I built that uses OpenLayers and google maps stopped working. Updating PrototypeJS from the ancient 1.7.rc3 to 1.7.2 did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Yes!! the solution for me was change the line from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3" />
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Change to version v3, the conflict with prototype will disappear, I have tried in my site, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This function at line number 629ish in prototype.js is causing the exception. Simply add try catch blocks as shown below. It works with any Google Maps API.

```js
collect: function(iterator, context) {
  iterator = iterator ? iterator.bind(context) : Prototype.K;
  var results = [];
  try {
    this.each(function(value, index) {
      results.push(iterator(value, index));
    });
  } catch (err) {}
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding parameter v=3.xx is obsolete coming 2024 april