# Google map controls are not showing in magento

Tags: google-maps, magento

I am facing problem in magento for the google map.
I have controller as the following:

```
class MapSoftware_Map_Adminhtml_MapbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    
public function indexAction()
    {
       $this->loadLayout();
       $this->_title($this->__("MapSales"));
       $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')->setTemplate('map/mapbackend.phtml')->toHtml();

        $this->_addContent($block);
       $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

I am going to use mapbackend.phtml file and its code is given below

```
<style>
#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    
  }
  #map-canvas img {  
        max-width: none;   
    }  
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=weather,places,drawing"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 8,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.1768697,37.9083264),
 mapTypeControl: true,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
  mapTypeIds: [
    google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  ]
},
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
 }
};
map = new    
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'),mapOptions);

 var image = 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-     
 flat/24/678111-map-marker-32.png';
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.1768697,37.9083264);
 var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image
     });
    }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
 <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 96%; height: 500px; position:    absolute;"></div>
```

So now my problem is when I go through the page it's showing only the map and not the controllers. This code is running on local machine but it's not working on magento.

Please help me , I am stuck with this part, also I am new in magento.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps and Richfaces 3.3.3 (prototype.js 1.6.0.3) possible incompatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505754/google-maps-and-richfaces-3-3-3-prototype-js-1-6-0-3-possible-incompatibility)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Google Map bug in the latest version that makes the map controls not visible and throws a JS error. I have seen the same problem in other places. Try with v3.17 instead.

Comment: It's working now, I have used the released version of google map, script library is given below.
 `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.10&sensor=false&signed_in=true"></script>`

Comment: Did you try with v3.17? You don't have to go all the way back to 3.10 if it works..

Comment: Yes, It's also working with v=3.17. Thank for your help.